# Azure Pipeline - How to make delayForMinutes task use value from variable instead of hardcoded value

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, pipeline, delay

How to make Delay task take value from variable instead of hardcoded value for delayForMinutes input?

When i do following, it works fine:

```
- job: WaitForDeploy
    dependsOn: Main
    pool: Server
    steps:
    - task: Delay@1
      inputs:
        delayForMinutes: '1'
```

but when i do it like this it does not:

```
- job: WaitForDeploy
    dependsOn: Main
    pool: Server
    steps:
    - task: Delay@1
      inputs:
        delayForMinutes: '$(SleepCount)'
```

**$(SleepCount)** is defined in variables as empty string and later on is passed from python script to pipeline via:
`print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable=SleepCount]{delay_seconds}')`
I am printing this out in previos job and it shows intiger correctly:

```
- script: 'echo $(SleepCount)'
      displayName: "print_sleep_count"
```

it looks like this variable value is not passed beyond job where i return it from python script, how to pass it?

This do not work:

```
variables:
  SleepCount: ""

jobs:
  - job: Main
    pool:
      name: 'CDaaSLinux'

    [...]

    - task: PythonScript@0
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'filePath'
        scriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/sleep_count.py'
      env:
        ACTUAL_START_DATE: $(ActualStartDate_value)

    - script: 'echo $(SleepCount)'
      name: setVariable
      displayName: "print_sleep_count"

    - script: 'echo "Waiting for Deploy for $(SleepCount) minutes"'
      displayName: "Deploy_message_for_user"
      
  - job: WaitForDeploy
    dependsOn: Main
    variables:
      SleepCount: $[ dependencies.Main.outputs['setVariable.SleepCount']]
    pool: Server
    steps:
    - task: Delay@1
      inputs:
        delayForMinutes: '$(SleepCount)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a variable in a different stage/job you need to set the isoutput flag when setting the variable

```
print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable=SleepCount;isoutput=true]{delay_seconds}')
```

[Set an output variable for use in future jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-jobs)

Comment: This helped. in this case i had to print variable inside python script as it was ```print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable=SleepCount]{delay_seconds}')``` and additionally echo it later inside yaml ```echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SleepCount2;isOutput=true]$(SleepCount)"```